# My internet connection not worked well in Win server 2012?

Tags: html, javascript, css

my computer (running on server 12). the internet is disconnected automatically. can someone take a look.

http://www.screencast.com/users/Kris01/folders/Default/media/a9917a3f-13f6-4237-b7a1-738a06d93997

Comment: Have you tried a different network cable?

Comment: last time The men (who have done it) told me it's not supported Win7 for USB PORTS. I only have one Ethernet port so that's the only way i can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have either a bad cable or a bad NIC. swap out the cable and see if that helps matters. If not, use a different NIC, or if a secondary NIC isnt available, Replace it.

Comment: I have seen a thing that when I give light to modem it's take 45 min and all days it's work fine. it's happen from last 5-6 days.

Comment: are you talking about link lights? I'm sorry, im not understanding what you're talking about.

Comment: @JaredTritsch I finally got a replacement for the product.it's have bugs and now new modem work fine. thanks for your help.

Comment: No worries. but if you could upvote and accept my answer that would be great, that way I can get credit.